# Use result of select query as column definition list in crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have created the function `n_months_crosstab(n)` which takes an integer as argument and returns a string representing my desired crosstab columns as text:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.n_months_crosstab(n integer)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$ 

with 
dates as (
    select ('"' || to_char(generate_series((now() - interval '1 months'*n)::date, now(), '1 month'), 'Mon-YY') || '"') months)
select concat('"Fund" text,', string_agg(dates.months, ' text,')||' text'::text) from dates;

$function$
```

Executing with `n=2` gives:

```
"Fund" text,"May-20" text,"Jun-20" text,"Jul-20" text
```

If I copy the returned value and use it as the crosstab query column definition list, I get my desired result.  But, how can I use the function call in place of its text output?

I would like to do something like:

```
select crosstab.* 
from crosstab('source sql','category sql')
as (select n_months_crosstab(2))
```

Instead of:

```
select crosstab.* 
from crosstab('source sql','category sql') 
as ("Fund" text,"May-20" text,"Jun-20" text,"Jul-20" text)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: is it inside the another function? if so, then you can use execute format. try reading https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-statements.html

Comment: Unfortunately it is not in a function. But thank you for the suggestion.